# Thymeleaf : How to set a conditional iteration based on a dynamic field?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

**View**: 
I have a form with two select fields : The second one only activates when a choice in the first one has been made and the content shown is relative to the first field.

**Model** : 
Establishment (id,name) 
Account  (id,Establishment)

**Logic** : 
 The first field loads a list of establishment from the model attribute "etablissements" that the Controller loads. 
The second field should then enable itself after a selection has been made (easy), but then it should also show a list of accounts that are "registered" to this Establishment.

The question is how do i set this kind of conditional statement in thymeleaf, knowing that I have access to all establishments and account in the template as shown here :

```
<form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate
                                    class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="addOP"
                                    th:object="${paiement}" method="post">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"
                                            for="first-name"> Compte <span class="required">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select class="form-control" th:field="*{idCompte}">
                                                <option th:each="account : ${etablissements}"
                                                    th:text="${etablissement.name}" th:value="${etablissement.name}">Choose
                                                    Etablissement</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"
                                            for="first-name"> Imputation <span class="required">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select class="form-control" disabled="disabled">
                                                <option th:each="account : ${accounts}"
                                                    th:text="${account.owner}" th:value="${account.id}">Compte</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

What's the best way to do this using thymeleaf or javascript ?

PS : Sorry for the formatting haven't found a way to automatically remove those spaces from code.

Answer (score 0):

You should still render the list using thymeleaf and give it a hidden class which sets it to `display: none`. Then with javascript you can add an eventlistener to the dropdown which looks for that specific value and removes the hidden class to show the list.

---

Edit: to filter the list you can put a [data attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) on the element and show or hide the item based on that data

Comment: That's the easy part, what I'm asking for is how to make the second field show only the accounts for the selected establishment.

Comment: You can put a data attribute on the element (in the thymeleaf template) and then hide or show the element based on the data. P.s. normally you can/would use some kind of Rest api for this